# What can traditional graph cut methods do well, that deep learning cannot?

Tags: optimization, combinatorial-optimization, graphs, applications, machine-learning

I have been fascinated by the ***rise and fall of graph cut algorithms*** in recent years, which I described in this question: [Was there something specific that caused graph cuts to lose popularity in the last 5 years?](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/2869/727)

On that question, I received an answer from an expert in the field. The main reason given for the ***drop*** in popularity of these algorithms, was the fact that graph cuts were mainly used for problems that **deep neural networks are now able to solve more accurately, without the need for optimization**.

But graph cuts were ***immensely*** popular during their heyday, and lead to many developments in mathematics (such as [quadratization](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/799/what-is-quadratization), as most [applications of quadratization](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/1380/727) and [QUBO](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/828/727) involve graph cuts). I would be amazed if nothing they provided us can beat neural networks for a useful problem. 2015 was not long ago, and in that year papers on graph cuts like [this one](https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=8Lp0W54AAAAJ&citation_for_view=8Lp0W54AAAAJ:u5HHmVD_uO8C) got almost 1000 citations in a single year alone! (more than some researchers get across all of their papers in a lifetime).

This makes me wonder: Is there any reason why I would ***rather use graph cuts*** than deep learning?